# How to remove duplicated results from a foreach loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, foreach, tags, categories

I'm trying to add some sidebar content to my WordPress search results page where the top categories and tags, related to the current search query, are displayed. I have been able to generate the content, but there are a massive amount of duplicates also displaying. [Click for my example page](http://dev.knowinggovernmentrelations.com/?s=pennsylvania).

I've tried two ways of doing this, both with no success. Both were pulled from previous threads with similar questions. I would prefer avoiding 3rd party plugins if possible. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks

Method #1:

```
function list_search_cats() {
  // Start the Loop
  $uniqueCats = array();
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $cats = get_the_category();

    if (! in_array($cats, $uniqueCats)) :
      $uniqueCats[] = $cats;
      foreach($cats as $cat) :
        echo '<li><a class="tag" href="'.get_category_link($cat->cat_ID).'">' . $cat->cat_name . '</a></li>';
      endforeach;
    endif;

  endwhile;

}
```

Method #2:

```
function list_search_cats() {
  // Start the Loop
  $uniqueCats = array();
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $cats = get_the_category();
    $cats = array_unique($cats, SORT_REGULAR);

    foreach($cats as $cat) :
      echo '<li><a class="tag" href="'.get_category_link($cat->cat_ID).'">' . $cat->cat_name . '</a></li>';
    endforeach;

  endwhile;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're just missing the actual check of each category.  You may need an extra foreach loop to check for dupes, then use that unique array in another foreach to display the categories.  Try this:

```
function list_search_cats() {
  // Array to put unique cats in
  $uniqueCats = array();

  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $cats[] = get_the_category();


   // first foreach to check each cat and put in to new array 

    foreach($cats as $cat) {

      if(!in_array($cat, $uniqueCats)) {
         $uniqueCats[] = $cat;
      }

    }

   // second foreach to display the list

    foreach($uniqueCats as $cat_li) {

     $term = get_term_by('name', $cat_li, 'category');

      echo '<li><a class="tag" href="'.get_category_link($term->term_id)).'">' . $cat_li . '</a></li>';

    }

  endwhile;

}
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking too, just didn't know how to execute it. Unfortunately, this did not work. I'm getting errors in the second foreach. It is unable to get the ID and name in the echo command. Sounds like the variable $cat_li is a 'non object'.

Comment: I don't know if this helps or not, but after further tinkering, it looks like my array is actually an array with multiple arrays inside it. Could this be what's causing the duplication? Can these arrays be pulled out into the root array?

Comment: What is likely occurring is that the second array just has a list of category names, and not the actual category object.  You will have to get the ID using the category name and simply echo each array item instead of using the name object.  I've made an adjustment to the answer to try.